# Change to folder of active subwindow using a Python script in QtiPlot

Tags: python, qt, scripting, plot, pyqt

I'm writing a python script which I want to use in `QtiPlot`, therefore I need to use `PyQt4`.

By changing the value of a `QCombobox` I want to change the active subwindow and (if it is in a different folder) change the active folder to the folder in which the subwindow is in.

Changing the subwindow is no problem. However I don't know how to determine the folder in which the window is in.

Here is the code of the function which is called on a SIGNAL emitted by the `QCombobox`:

```
def windowChange():
    w = qti.app.activeFolder()
    aw = w.window(ui.windowBox.currentText())
    changeFolder(aw.folder())
    ws.setActiveSubWindow(aw)
```

I tried many different things instead of `aw.folder()` but nothing worked.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "folder in which the subwindow is in", I don't see how a window can be in a folder. The Qti application has a project folder. The active folder points somewhere in there. Once a folder becomes active, it is active for the whole application. See http://soft.proindependent.com/doc/manual-en/x6311.html#Python-Folders. Also, in your example the w is active folder, so you don't need to change to it, it is already active. Simply `changeFolder(w)`, where w is the project folder you want, should impact all application windows.

Comment: Within a Qti-project there is a folder structure to organize your windows (which for example can be tables or graphs). By using the command `w.window(ui.windowBox.currentText())` I can get access to a window which can be within a subfolder of the current active folder. So the window itself is not visible at that moment.

Comment: got it, thanks for clarification, sorry can't help